# How to install tensorflow lite c++ on windows?

Tags: windows, c++11, qt-creator, tensorflow-lite, mingw32

I am currently trying to install Tensorflowlite in a Windows environment.
My project is based on c++ and my compiler uses mingw g++, gcc.
IDE is using a qt creator, but they can't find a suitable way to install it in this environment, so I leave this message.
Do you know any links or methods to refer to how to install in the above environment?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to build a shared TensorFlowLite yet, but static build of version 2.4.1 in MSYS2 shell using MinGW-w64 compiler works when I do this (I'm using CMake and Ninja):

```
# change the line below to the installation location
INSTALLPREFIX=/C/Temp
cmake -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DFETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED:BOOL=OFF -DCPUINFO_BUILD_TOOLS:BOOL=ON -DTFLITE_ENABLE_GPU:BOOL=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_RUY:BOOL=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_NNAPI:BOOL=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK:BOOL=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_MMAP:BOOL=OFF -DFXDIV_BUILD_BENCHMARKS:BOOL=OFF -DFXDIV_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DCLOG_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DCPUINFO_BUILD_MOCK_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DCPUINFO_BUILD_UNIT_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DEIGEN_BUILD_BTL:BOOL=OFF -Stensorflow/lite -Bbuild_static &&
 ( ninja -Cbuild_static install/strip ||
  (
   # fix farmhash
   sed -i.bak -e "s/if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_*)/& || defined(_WIN32)/" build_static/farmhash/src/farmhash.h &&
   echo -e '@@ -168 +168 @@\n-#else\n+#elif !defined(_WIN32)' | patch -ulbf build_static/farmhash/src/farmhash.cc &&
   ninja -Cbuild_static install/strip ) || 
  (
   # fix missing max()
   mv build_static/cpuinfo-source/src/x86/windows/init.c build_static/cpuinfo-source/src/x86/windows/init.c.bak &&
   echo "#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))" > build_static/cpuinfo-source/src/x86/windows/init.c &&
   cat build_static/cpuinfo-source/src/x86/windows/init.c.bak >> build_static/cpuinfo-source/src/x86/windows/init.c &&
   ninja -Cbuild_static install/strip
  )
 ) &&
 echo SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with various environment would be to build the library separately, and link that library to your project. Please refer to following links for building on Windows.

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows (whole TensorFlow)
- https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake

Comment: I tried to build using the bazel in the above way, but it seems like I can't find the path of Python path. Could you tell me about your knowledge on how to build using bazel?